# How to format delta when relative is True in indicators (python)

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, plotly-python

I am trying to format the `delta` part of an indicator in python. When `relative` is set to `False`, the `delta` is expressed as an integer and I am able to round the `delta` to 2 decimal places, from 179 to 178.6. But when `relative` is set to `True`, the `delta` is a float (81.061...%) and when I try to round it to two decimal I get (0.81). Is it possible to get the percentage change rounded to two decimal places i.e. 81.06%.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Indicator(
    mode = "number+delta",
    value = 400.1456,
    domain = {'x': [0, 0.5], 'y': [0.5, 1]},
    delta = {'reference': 221.544, 'relative': False},
    title = {"text": "<span style='font-size:0.8em'>'relative': False</span>"}
    )) 

fig.add_trace(go.Indicator(
    mode = "number+delta",
    value = 400.1456,
    domain = {'x': [0, 0.5], 'y': [0, 0.5]},
    delta = {'reference': 221.544, 'relative': False, "valueformat": ".2f"},
    title = {"text": "<span style='font-size:0.8em'>'relative': False, 'valueformat': '.2f'</span>"}
    )) 

fig.add_trace(go.Indicator(
    mode = "number+delta",
    value = 400.1456,
    domain = {'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0.5, 1]},
    delta = {'reference': 221, 'relative': True},
    title = {"text": "<span style='font-size:0.8em'>'relative': True</span>"}
    ))

fig.add_trace(go.Indicator(
    mode = "number+delta",
    value = 400.1456,
    domain = {'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 0.5]},
    delta = {'reference': 221, 'relative': True, "valueformat": ".2f"},
    title = {"text": "<span style='font-size:0.8em'>'relative': True, 'valueformat': '.2f'</span>"}
    )) 

fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  `"valueformat": ".2%"` as follows:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()


fig.add_trace(go.Indicator(
    mode = "number+delta",
    value = 420,
    domain = {'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0.5, 1]},
    delta = {'reference': 221, 'relative': True, "valueformat": ".2%"},

    ))

fig.add_trace(go.Indicator(
    mode = "number+delta",
    value = 400.1456,
    domain = {'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 0.5]},
    delta = {'reference': 221, 'relative': True, "valueformat": ".2%"},
    )) 

fig.show()
```

**Output**
[image]